# How to implement pagination for dynamic inner datasource inside other mat-table?

Tags: angular, angular-material-table

I have a mat-table which is nested inside other mat-table.
The datasource for the nested mat-table is an array of objects from first mat-table.

I want to bind a pagination for the inner dataSource:  `[dataSource]="element.users"`.
How can I reach this? I have been searching here in SO and trying couple of options, but none of them did work. Any Idea, how to manage such use case?

Code - HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let el of adminsList">
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="myDataSource" multiTemplateDataRows ...>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
              <div>{{el['version'] }}</div>
          </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;">
              <table mat-table [dataSource]="element.users">
                 <ng-container matColumnDef="{{innerColumn}}" *ngFor="let innerColumn of columnsToDisplay">
                     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                        {{innerColumn }}
                     </th>
                     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                        {{element[innerColumn]}}
                     </td>
                 </ng-container>
                 <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
                 <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: columnsToDisplay"></tr>
              </table>
              <mat-paginator [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                        showFirstLastButtons]="true" #innerPaginator>
              </mat-paginator>
          </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="deployedVersion">
        // display: none to hide the outer table column headers
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="display: none"></th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="display: none"></td>
    </ng-container>
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay"></tr>
  </table>
</ng-container>
```

Code - TS:

```
@ViewChild('innerPaginator') innerPaginator: MatPaginator;
innerDataSourceObject: any;
...
...
this.userService.getUserInfo().subscribe((res: userData) => {
    ...
    this.innerDataSourceObject = new MatTableDataSource<EnvComponents>(res);
    ...
});
...
...
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.innerDataSourceObject.innerPaginator.paginator = this.innerPaginator;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mat-paginator can be use when the dataSource is a MatTableDataSource or "standalone". I imagine you element.users is an array, so you should use as "standalone"

To use as standalone, is simple use [slice pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe) in your source

As you use a template ReferenceVariable "innerPaginator" you can get the value of the innerPaginator.pageIndex (starts with 0) and innerPaginator.pageSize

You need add the property length to the paginator (you can see the example in the [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/paginator/overview))

```
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;">
          <table mat-table [dataSource]="element.users
             |slice:(innerPaginator.pageIndex*innerPaginator.pageSize)
                   :((innerPaginator.pageIndex+1)*innerPaginator.pageSize)">

              ...

          </table>
          <mat-paginator #innerPaginator [length]="element.users.length"
                [pageSize]="5" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
                                               showFirstLastButtons]="true">
          </mat-paginator>
      </td>
```

You needn't worry about the ["scope"](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#template-variable-scope) of the templateRef because is inside a *ngFor

Comment: Yes, the `element.users` is an array of objects. I'll give the standalone concept a try. Thanks

Comment: The table is empty now and no errors. No data. When I output the length: `Length: {{element.users.length}}`, it says: `core.mjs:7640 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`

Comment: try use the safe operator if there're no users: `element.users?.length` or `element.users?.length || 0`

Comment: The issue comes from these assignments: `@ViewChild('innerPaginator') innerPaginator: MatPaginator;`
`ngAfterViewInit() { this.dSrcObject.innerPaginator.paginator = this.innerPaginator; }`. Error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerPaginator')` and `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pageIndex')`

Comment: you needn't ViewChild, it's all controller by the .html

Comment: Have already been trying it without `ViewChild`, but I got: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pageIndex')`. I'am going wrong some where

Comment: Ok. Working now. Just one thing comes up. Paginator is available and I can use it correctly. But it repeats the Paginator  may time as the outer `dataSource` in the first `mat-table`: `[dataSource]="myDataSource"` Weird!

Comment: Fixed. Working as expected now. Last issue was related to the first loop in `ng-container`: `<ng-container *ngFor="let el of adminsList">`. My bad. Thanks!